# Regular expression for pattern "Form 1987A"

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I need to extract out a string from a phrase and the extracted string should match a defined pattern. I am using java regex Pattern, Matcher. Only thing I need are the regular expression's for the following pattern strings:

- **Form 1987** *(i.e "Form" keyword followed by a space followed by any 4 digit number)*
- **Form 1987A** *(i.e "Form" keyword followed by a space followed by any 4 digit number and capital A)*
- **Form 1987-A** *(i.e "Form" keyword followed by a space followed by any 4 digit number and -A)*

**Update 1**

Also the regex should find the match only when the phrase starts with "**Form**" keyword and not when "Form 1987" appears in the middle of the phrase. Ex.

"I am watching **Form 1987** Monuments Men" - should not match
"**Form 1987** I am watching Monuments Men" - should match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also match all form with one regex:

```
Form\s\d{4}-?A?
```

Use double backslash `\\` if you want to put it directly into Java code

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gC2eI7/1)

Comment: @Mshnik   how to i modify this regex to make sure the string Starts with "Form" keyword. the regex mentioned above can find the string in between   a pharase. Eg. "You are awesome!!  Form 1974Z thank you"

Comment: Can this [Form\s\d{4}-?A?] be modified to accept a match if I have either of S,R,T,H in place of ?A?.

Comment: @Maverick `Form\s\d{4}-?[ASRTH]?` inside [ ] brackets you insert characters you want to literaly match

Comment: Thank U. +1 for the answer. did u have any fix for the Update 1

Comment: @Maverick `^Form\s\d{4}-?[ASRTH]?` should do the trick, however if you deal with more than one line of input at once, you will need to use multiline mode: `Pattern.MULTILINE` or add `(?m)` before regex

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly simple pattern to match, as the number must be exactly 4 digits. Here are the patterns you want; simply wrap them in a java pattern and match away.

1. Form [0-9]{4}
2. Form [0-9]{4}A
3. Form [0-9]{4}-A

You can play around with regexes [here](http://regexpal.com/) to find test them out and learn more about regexes.